# Need to put the condition to avoid duplicate routes coming from google APIs in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays

```
['DRIVING', true, 'CAR (Without Tolls)', 0],
['DRIVING', false, 'CAR (With Tolls)', 0],
```

When I call Driving routes two times with `avoidTolls:false` and `avoidTolls:true`, the routes that return in both arrays repeat. I am trying to develop a condition or a check to avoid the duplication of routes. I am using javascript.Can somebody please guide with code how to intersect the arrays, identify the duplicates and break the loop. Thanks!
The code so far I have

```
directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            if(k==0) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
               alert(j);
                if(j==0){

                    var u = 0;
                    while(response.routes.length > u) {
                        distance[u] = response.routes[u].legs[0].distance.text;
                        alert(distance [u]);
                        u++;
                    }
                }
                if(j==1){

                    var z = 0;
                    while(response.routes.length > z) {
                        var index = distance.indexOf(response.routes[z].legs[0].distance.text);
                        if(index > -1){
                            var getIndex = distance.indexOf(response.routes[z]);
                            if(getIndex > -1) {
                                response.routes.splice(getIndex,1);
                            }
                        }
                        z++;
                    }
                }
```

I am trying to capture the distance of the routes and applying a check that if they are same, they should not appear, but so far its not working so far, rather it is not returning the correct values of alert (j);

`for (var j = 0; j < mode_options.length; j++) {
        var request = {
            origin: source,
            destination: destination,
            provideRouteAlternatives: true,
            travelMode: mode_options[j][0],
            transitOptions: {
                departureTime: future_date
            },
            avoidTolls: mode_options[j][1],
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,

            region: 'AU'
        };`
   This is the code i am using to call the driving routes.

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Comment: @TZHX The code to avoid duplication?

Comment: Yes. That. Stack Overflow doesn't work well for people just asking "I want code that does this". You need to put what you've tried so far and explain how it didn't work.

Comment: Edit the code into your question, don't post it as a comment. [Click here to edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29673794/edit).